# BIND9 constant servfail

Tags: dns, bind, server

I want to create dns server on my VPS and add a domain to it from another provider. Domain is set in provider's panel to VPS as dns1 and sdns2.ovh.net as dns2. I'm getting SERVFAIL from dig over and over again and since I'm new to this I'm out of moves. What is wrong?

my zone file for domain.com:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. root.ns1.domain.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@                IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
@                IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.
@                IN      A       176.31.189.10
ns1              IN      A       176.31.189.10
ns2              IN      A       213.251.188.141
```

named-checkzone shows OK

named.conf entry:

```
zone "domain.com" {
    type master;
    file "db.domain.com";
};
```

named.conf.options:

```
options  {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;


    listen-on-v6 port 53 {
        any;
    };

    listen-on port 53 {
        any;
    };
};
```

Port 53 is allowed by firewall in/out. Bind service is active.

I'm getting dig SERVFAIL all the time.
My dns2 provider requires "ownercheck" but i cant do it since it looks like the zone file is not being read anyhow.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved
server was failing to load zone file - lack of full address

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case was to ensure that `/etc/bind` was actually writable by the `bind` user, since bind tries to place a compiled `*.jnl` file of the zone file there.

Also, [enabling full logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153958/how-to-enable-named-bind-dns-full-logging) helps to spot newbie errors like this easily... :)